# Using cumsum to find unique chapters

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

  text      secFlag  
0  book     1 
1  headings 1 
2  chapter  1 
3  one      1
4  page     0 
5  one      0
6  text     0
7  chapter   1 
8  two       1 
9  page     0 
10  two      0
11  text     0 
12  page      0
13  three     0
10  text      0
11  chapter   1 
12  three     1
13  something  0
```

I want to find the cumulative sum so that I can mark all the pages belonging to a specific chapter by a running index number.

```
**Desired output**


  text      secFlag  chapter
0  book     1       1
1  headings 1       1
2  chapter  1       2
3  one      1       2
4  page     0       2
5  one      0       2
6  text     0       2
7  chapter   1      3
8  two       1      3
9  page     0      3
10  two      0     3
11  text     0      3
12  page      0     3
13  three     0     3
10  text      0     3
11  chapter   1      4
12  three     1     4
13  something  0     4
```

This is what I tried:

```
df['chapter'] = ((df['secFlag'].shift(-1) == 1)).cumsum()
```

But, this is not giving me the desired output, as it is incrementing as soon as a value is 1 in the section flag. Note that multiple words are part of the text, and the chapter heading will usually have multiple words.

Can you please suggest a simple way to get this done?
thanks

Comment: Is expected output correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need flag by first `1` in `secFlag` solution is:

```
df['chapter'] = ((df['secFlag'] == 1) & (df['secFlag'] != df['secFlag'].shift())).cumsum()
print (df)
         text  secFlag  chapter
0        book        1        1
1    headings        1        1
2     chapter        1        1
3         one        1        1
4        page        0        1
5         one        0        1
6        text        0        1
7     chapter        1        2
8         two        1        2
9        page        0        2
10        two        0        2
11       text        0        2
12       page        0        2
13      three        0        2
10       text        0        2
11    chapter        1        3
12      three        1        3
13  something        0        3
```

**Details**:

```
a = (df['secFlag'] == 1)
b = (df['secFlag'] != df['secFlag'].shift())
c = a & b
d = c.cumsum()

print (pd.concat([df,a,b,c,d], 
                 axis=1, 
                 keys=('orig','==1','!=shifted','chained by &','cumsum')))
         orig             ==1 !=shifted chained by &  cumsum
         text secFlag secFlag   secFlag      secFlag secFlag
0        book       1    True      True         True       1
1    headings       1    True     False        False       1
2     chapter       1    True     False        False       1
3         one       1    True     False        False       1
4        page       0   False      True        False       1
5         one       0   False     False        False       1
6        text       0   False     False        False       1
7     chapter       1    True      True         True       2
8         two       1    True     False        False       2
9        page       0   False      True        False       2
10        two       0   False     False        False       2
11       text       0   False     False        False       2
12       page       0   False     False        False       2
13      three       0   False     False        False       2
10       text       0   False     False        False       2
11    chapter       1    True      True         True       3
12      three       1    True     False        False       3
13  something       0   False      True        False       3
```

Comment: Thank you- the chapter value for the first 4 lines are incorrect [ you have indicated the correct values!] thanks!